Morse code help with vocaroo
https://vocaroo.com/1nSJsgpYz2nj
trying to decode this but I'm not good at interpreting morse code. First character is B. How can I read the voice clip?

what does this have to do with "vocaroo", which only seems to be a service where you can host audio snippets?

I ask because you put "vocaroo" in the title, so I assume that's not just a irrelevant detail to you! To me it leaves me to wonder whether your question is about usage of that website, or about Morse?

ping, cs95? Could you clarify?

Hm, four days and no clarification: voted to close this question as lacking clarity. If the question gets closed, don't despair! You can still edit the question to add the information asked for, and that will put it in a queue for reviewing whether the question can be reopened.
